# set dimension of svd algorithm in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

svd formular：  `A ≈ UΣV*`
I use numpy.linalg.svd to run svd algorithm.
And I want to set dimension of matrix.

For example: `A=3*5` dimension, after running numpy.linalg.svd, `U=3*3` dimension, `Σ=3*1` dimension, `V*=5*5` dimension.

I need to set specific dimension like `U=3*64` dimension, `V*=64*5` dimension. But it seems there is no optional dimension parameter can be set in numpy.linalg.svd.

Comment: Read about [`numpy array subsetting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` is a `3 x 5` matrix then it has rank at most 3. Therefore the SVD of `A` contains at most 3 singular values. Note that in your example above, the singular values are stored as a vector instead of a diagonal matrix. Trivially this means that you can pad your matrices with zeroes at the bottom. Since the full S matrix contains of 3 values on the diagonal followed by the rest 0's (in your case it would be 64x64 with 3 nonzero values), the bottom rows of V and the right rows of U don't interact at all and can be set to anything you want.

Keep in mind that this isn't the SVD of A anymore, but instead the condensed SVD of the matrix augmented with a lot of 0's.